# Laravel 5 Token Mismatch Error in User Login

Tags: laravel, token

Sometimes my clients feedback me there exists token mismatch error.

I increased timeout. But sometimes it happens. Can we regenerate token instead of showing whoops message ? Because it is not good for users.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your code in a try-catch block, and catch the `Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException`, and redirect your user back or wherever you need.

Guys [here](http://laravel.io/forum/01-30-2015-laravel5-tokenmismatchexception-in-verifycsrftoken/?page=2) say that it may be due to difference in timezone setup.